# When is a linked list the best data structure to use

Tags: data-structures, complexity-theory

like the title really. My question is can you give an example where a linked list is the BEST data structure to use. I have been struggling to think of any really, and in my code I pretty much always just use hashmaps or lists etc.

http://bigocheatsheet.com/ Here you can see the cheat sheet of Big O's for various operations. A linked list is no better than a stack or a queue in terms of complexity. And so I wanted to know when someone might use a linked list over these for example? A perfect answer will say "Imagine I was trying to do XYZ, if I did it with an array it would look like this  {enter some code}, however, if I do it with a linked list, it will look like this {enter more code}. The complexities or space are substantially better for the linked list." etc.

I don't want an answer where someone tells me WHAT a linked list is. I know what a linked list is and how they are implemented.

Thanks

Comment: When the number of elements is small, a linked list - because if its simplicity - can be quicker than a more elaborate data structure.

Comment: When you want less complexity or no complexity at all. Linked lists are easier to grasp than other complex structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider if you have a line-up of people, and somewhere in the middle you want to add a lot of people. If you used a conventional ArrayList, you would need to shift all elements after it, so O(N) because of indexing per person! In a LinkedList, each person would be O(1), with O(N) to get to the middle. Linked Lists are very quick in adding elements in the middle, as you don't need to reindex anything and just adjust the local pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Someone dd a survey of the C++ standard template library and found that the linked list was the least used of all the common basic structures. So you're right they they are not much used. They're useful when you don't need random access to an array, when you don't know N or have a reasonably tight upper bound on N, and when insertions and deletions are common and time critical. An insertion in the middle is O(N), as with an array, but the actual operation is a lot cheaper (pointer dereference rather than memory shifting), insertions at the beginning are O(1), and at the end if you keep an end pointer.